# Node.js Mongodb Callback issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My app should update if tmx is newer, if older do nothing and if doesn't exist insert the document.
If the document is inserted, it works perfectly, else it doesn't update properly or says E11000 dup key.
trying to figure out if my callback are wrong or the logic. (I'm new to node.js+mongodb)      MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
            assert = require('assert'),
            url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/pfc';

```
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        run(db);
    });


    function run(db) {
        fs.readFile('log.log', 'utf8', function (err, source) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dataFile = JSON.parse(source);
            dataFile.forEach(function (item) {
                upsert(db, item, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) console.dir(err);

                });
            });
        })
    }

    function upsert(db, doc, callback) {

    db.collection('flags').findOne({vid: doc.vid}, function (err, item, result) {

        if (item.vid != null) {
            if (!(item.tmx instanceof Date)) {
                item.tmx = new Date(item.tmx)
            }
            if(!(doc.tmx instanceof Date)){
                doc.tmx = new Date(doc.tmx)
            }

            if (item.tmx < doc.tmx) {
                console.dir("Date validation")
                db.collection('flags').updateOne({vid: item.vid}, {
                        $set: {
                            "tmx": doc.tmx
                        }
                    },{upsert:true}, function (err, result) {
                        callback(err, result);

                    }
                )

                callback(err, result);
            }
            else{
                console.dir("older")
                callback(err, result);
            }
        }
        else {
            db.collection('flags').insertOne(doc, function(err, result) {
                callback(err, result);
            });
        }
    })}
```

Edit:
The documents from the 'log.log' file have this structure:

{
vid:2848
tmx: "2015-07-18T23:56:17.000Z"
}

{
vid: 2848
tmx: 2015-07-19T00:00:17.000Z
}

collection.find({vid: doc.vid},function(err,item){

if(!item) // didnt find in collection, items with vid: 2848
insert doc to collection
else if(item) //found an item with vid:2848
  if (item.tmx < doc.tmx)//only update if doc.tmx is newer
    update collection with the most recent document

with @Aaron Dufour help I got rid of the callback problem, thanks :)
but now the problem is when I have the collection already populated and go look for newest documents in log.log, it starts from the oldest document till the newest again :(

Comment: Your upsert logic is vulnerable to race conditions, which could be causing the issues.  Have you tried Mongo's built-in upsert?

Comment: Can't see how to use it when I have to compare the dates to update

Comment: since if the item doesn't exist I get item.tmx property of null error, so I need to confirm the item exists so I can compare  the date from the file with the date from mongodb

Comment: Do you have multiple documents with the same `vid` value?

Comment: yes I have. the file has more than 60000 documents now
and I have an average 40 documents with same vid

Comment: The code you implied otherwise, so I assumed that would hold.  It isn't clear what you want to do when there are multiple (`findOne` is essentially non-deterministic in that case).  I would suggest opening a new question that is much clearer on these points.  It also isn't clear what `doc` might look like (my answer is probably wrong if it contains anything other than `vid` and `tmx`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `upsert` is vulnerable to race conditions, and `run` calls it many times in parallel, so that is probably the issue.  It is not clear exactly what `doc` will look like, so you might need slightly more complicated logic, but here's a version that uses Mongo's `upsert` to make things a bit safer:

```
function upsert(db, doc, callback) {
  db.collection('flags').update({vid: doc.vid}, {$set: doc}, {upsert: true}, function(err) {
    db.collection('flags').update({vid: doc.vid, tmx: {$lt: doc.tmx}}, {$set: tmx: doc.tmx}, function(err) {
      callback();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: m8 you are a genius, saved my life :D

Comment: found a little bug, 
For example, oldest record is from 07/08/2015 00:00:17 and newest is from today.
If I run the application again, it will update to the oldest and go till the new again, the ways I tried didn't work. :(

How to avoid this?

Comment: @TelmoIvo I don't understand the problem you're having. Maybe edit it into the question so you have more room to explain it?

Comment: added more details at the end of the question.